# Button and Slider Stop Responding After Rotations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I have a test app that uses a custom container controller to switch between 2 child view controllers based on the orientation of the device. In the portraitController, I have a button and a slider -- after one rotation to landscape and back to portrait, the slider still works but the button doesn't. After one more back and forth, both UI elements stop responding to touches.

Meanwhile, in the landscapeController, the button works fine for the first 6 times you switch to that controller, but on the 7th, the button only responds on the far left side, and on the 8th, it no longer responds at all.

The views look fine after the rotations -- everything stays in the right place. There's no methods connected to these UI elements I'm just seeing if they are responsive to touch. I have strong references to both child view controllers, so I am presenting the same instance on each rotation. I can post the code for the container controller if it would help.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: try enable clipping for all views, may be they resize when your change orientation.

Comment: @NeverBe, you're definitely on to something there, but I can't figure out how to fix it. If I check the "clip subviews" box of the controllers' views, then I see the button disappear after one rotation and the slider after 2. I've tried using auto layout, and many many combinations of the struts and springs without success. The way I had it originally, the views appear to all stay in place correctly, but with clipping turned on, they disappear -- is this because the main view is moving?

Comment: May be it' moving, may be not. You can try to resize subviews to superview bounds after orientation has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after much experimenting -- the "Autoresize Subviews" check box in the container controller's view needs to be deselected. I'm not sure what that does exactly, but it was inappropriately resizing the views of the child controllers.